# Best way to make Django's login_required the default

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a large Django app, the vast majority of which requires a login to access.  This means that all throughout our app we've sprinkled:

```
@login_required
def view(...):
```

That's fine, and it works great *as long as we remember to add it everywhere*!  Sadly sometimes we forget, and the failure often isn't terribly evident.  If the only link to a view is on a @login_required page then you're not likely to notice that you can actually reach that view without logging in.  But the bad guys might notice, which is a problem.

My idea was to reverse the system.  Instead of having to type @login_required everywhere, instead I'd have something like:

```
@public
def public_view(...):
```

Just for the public stuff.  I tried to implement this with some middleware and I couldn't seem to get it to work.  Everything I tried interacted badly with other middleware we're using, I think.  Next up I tried writing something to traverse the URL patterns to check that everything that's not @public was marked @login_required - at least then we'd get a quick error if we forgot something.  But then I couldn't figure out how to tell if @login_required had been applied to a view...

So, what's the right way to do this?  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Excellent question. I've been in exactly the same position. We have middleware for making the *entire site* login_required, and we have a home-grown ACL of sorts for showing different views/template-fragments to different people/roles, but this is different from either of those.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Middleware may be your best bet.  I've used this piece of code in the past, modified from a snippet found elsewhere:

```
import re

from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required


class RequireLoginMiddleware(object):
    """
    Middleware component that wraps the login_required decorator around
    matching URL patterns. To use, add the class to MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES and
    define LOGIN_REQUIRED_URLS and LOGIN_REQUIRED_URLS_EXCEPTIONS in your
    settings.py. For example:
    ------
    LOGIN_REQUIRED_URLS = (
        r'/topsecret/(.*)$',
    )
    LOGIN_REQUIRED_URLS_EXCEPTIONS = (
        r'/topsecret/login(.*)$',
        r'/topsecret/logout(.*)$',
    )
    ------
    LOGIN_REQUIRED_URLS is where you define URL patterns; each pattern must
    be a valid regex.

    LOGIN_REQUIRED_URLS_EXCEPTIONS is, conversely, where you explicitly
    define any exceptions (like login and logout URLs).
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self.required = tuple(re.compile(url) for url in settings.LOGIN_REQUIRED_URLS)
        self.exceptions = tuple(re.compile(url) for url in settings.LOGIN_REQUIRED_URLS_EXCEPTIONS)

    def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
        # No need to process URLs if user already logged in
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            return None

        # An exception match should immediately return None
        for url in self.exceptions:
            if url.match(request.path):
                return None

        # Requests matching a restricted URL pattern are returned
        # wrapped with the login_required decorator
        for url in self.required:
            if url.match(request.path):
                return login_required(view_func)(request, *view_args, **view_kwargs)

        # Explicitly return None for all non-matching requests
        return None
```

Then in settings.py, list the base URLs you want to protect:

```
LOGIN_REQUIRED_URLS = (
    r'/private_stuff/(.*)$',
    r'/login_required/(.*)$',
)
```

As long as your site follows URL conventions for the pages requiring authentication, this model will work.  If this isn't a one-to-one fit, you may choose to modify the middleware to suit your circumstances more closely.

What I like about this approach - besides removing the necessity of littering the codebase with `@login_required` decorators - is that if the authentication scheme changes, you have one place to go to make global changes.

Comment: Thanks, this looks great!  It didn't occur to me to actually use login_required() in my middleware.  I think this will help work around the problem I was having playing nice with our middleware stack.

Comment: Doh! This is almost exactly the pattern we used for a group of pages that *had* to be HTTPS, and everything else must *not* be HTTPS. That was 2.5 years ago and I had completely forgotten about it. Thanx, Daniel!

Comment: Yup, this seems to work!  I added a @public decorator which marks the function so I can recognize it without duplicating the URL, but otherwise your code is perfect.  Thanks!

Comment: The middleware RequireLoginMiddleware class should be placed where? views.py, models.py?

Comment: @yasin check this out for writing middleware: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/http/middleware/#writing-your-own-middleware

Comment: @samtregar how did you get the `@public` decorator to work in conjunction with the middleware? don't you still have to explicitly list all public urls in the settings because the middleware would run before the decorator?

Comment: @richard decorators run at compile time, and in this case all I did was: function.public = True.  Then when the middleware runs it can look for the .public flag on the function to decide whether to allow the access or not.  If that doesn't make sense I can send you the full code.

Comment: I think the best approach is to make `@public` decorator, which sets `_public` attribute on view, and middleware then skips those views. Django's [csrf_exempt](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/_modules/django/views/decorators/csrf/#csrf_exempt) decorator works the same way

Comment: In case you use internationalization (with django-cms for instance), you can simply change `LOGIN_REQUIRED_URLS` to `r'/(.*)/my_url/(.*)$'`. That way, you can account for the language changes before `my_url`.

Comment: I want to limit the access of one app, called app, if the user doesn't have login.
The middleware RequireLoginMiddleware class should be placed where?

Comment: For Django 1.10+ see [np8's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46976284/), which is written for the new Django middleware.

Comment: I'm getting this error ->
process_request() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'view_func', 'view_args', and 'view_kwargs'

for the required logins. Can anyone help me, please? I'm using Django 2.2

Answer (score 32):

There is an alternative to putting a decorator on each view function. You can also put the `login_required()` decorator in the `urls.py` file.
While this is still a manual task, at least you have it all in one place, which makes it easier to audit.

e.g.,

```
    from my_views import home_view

    urlpatterns = patterns('',
        # "Home":
        (r'^$', login_required(home_view), dict(template_name='my_site/home.html', items_per_page=20)),
    )
```

Note that view functions are named and imported directly, not as strings.

Also note that this works with any callable view object, including classes.

Answer (score 5):

In Django 2.1, we can [decorate all methods in a class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-the-class) with:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class ProtectedView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'secret.html'
```

**UPDATE:**
I have also found the following to work:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

class ProtectedView(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'secret.html'
```

and set `LOGIN_URL = '/accounts/login/'` in your *settings.py*

Comment: thanks for this new answer. but please explain lil bit about it, i couldnt get it even if i read the official doc. thanks for ya help in advance

Comment: @TianLoon please see my updated answer, it may help.

Comment: LoginRequiredMixin not redirect link from settings.py, in django 4. Use @login_required

Answer (score 3):

## Here is a middleware solution for django 1.10+

The middlewares in [have to be written in a new way in django 1.10+](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/releases/1.10/#new-style-middleware).

#### Code

```
import re

from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required


class RequireLoginMiddleware(object):

    def __init__(self, get_response):
         # One-time configuration and initialization.
        self.get_response = get_response

        self.required = tuple(re.compile(url)
                              for url in settings.LOGIN_REQUIRED_URLS)
        self.exceptions = tuple(re.compile(url)
                                for url in settings.LOGIN_REQUIRED_URLS_EXCEPTIONS)

    def __call__(self, request):

        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response

    def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):

        # No need to process URLs if user already logged in
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            return None

        # An exception match should immediately return None
        for url in self.exceptions:
            if url.match(request.path):
                return None

        # Requests matching a restricted URL pattern are returned
        # wrapped with the login_required decorator
        for url in self.required:
            if url.match(request.path):
                return login_required(view_func)(request, *view_args, **view_kwargs)

        # Explicitly return None for all non-matching requests
        return None
```

## Installation

1. Copy the code into your project folder, and save as middleware.py
2. Add to MIDDLEWARE

   MIDDLEWARE = [
       ...
       '.middleware.RequireLoginMiddleware',  # Require login
   ]
3. Add to your settings.py:

```py
LOGIN_REQUIRED_URLS = (
    r'(.*)',
)
LOGIN_REQUIRED_URLS_EXCEPTIONS = (
    r'/admin(.*)$',
)
LOGIN_URL = '/admin'
```

#### Sources:

1. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2164224/3015186) by Daniel Naab
2. [Django Middleware tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BtxnjcVl68M) by Max Goodridge
3. [Django Middleware Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/)

Comment: Note that although nothing happens in `__call__`, the `process_view` hook is still used [edited]

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to change the built-in assumptions in Django without reworking the way url's are handed off to view functions.

Instead of mucking about in Django internals, here's an audit you can use.  Simply check each view function.

```
import os
import re

def view_modules( root ):
    for path, dirs, files in os.walk( root ):
        for d in dirs[:]:
            if d.startswith("."):
                dirs.remove(d)
        for f in files:
            name, ext = os.path.splitext(f)
            if ext == ".py":
                if name == "views":
                    yield os.path.join( path, f )

def def_lines( root ):
    def_pat= re.compile( "\n(\S.*)\n+(^def\s+.*:$)", re.MULTILINE )
    for v in view_modules( root ):
        with open(v,"r") as source:
            text= source.read()
            for p in def_pat.findall( text ):
                yield p

def report( root ):
    for decorator, definition in def_lines( root ):
        print decorator, definition
```

Run this and examine the output for `def`s without appropriate decorators.

Answer (score 2):

As of Django 3+, you can change the default like the followings:

> Step 1: Create a new file anything.py in your yourapp directory and write the following:

```
import re
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

//for registering a class as middleware you at least __init__() and __call__()
//for this case we additionally need process_view() which will be automatically called by Django before rendering a view/template

class ClassName(object):
    
    //need for one time initialization, here response is a function which will be called to get response from view/template
    def __init__(self, response):
        self.get_response = response
        self.required = tuple(re.compile(url) for url in settings.AUTH_URLS)
        self.exceptions = tuple(re.compile(url)for url in settings.NO_AUTH_URLS)

    def __call__(self, request):
        //any code written here will be called before requesting response
        response = self.get_response(request)
        //any code written here will be called after response
        return response

    //this is called before requesting response
    def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
        //if authenticated return no exception
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            return None
                
        //default case, no exception
        return login_required(view_func)(request, *view_args, **view_kwargs)
```

> Step 2: Add this anything.py to Middleware[] in project/settings.py like followings

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    // your previous middleware
    'yourapp.anything.ClassName',
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by Ber's answer I wrote a little snippet that replaces the `patterns` function, by wrapping all of the URL callbacks with the `login_required` decorator. This works in Django 1.6.

```
def login_required_patterns(*args, **kw):
    for pattern in patterns(*args, **kw):
        # This is a property that should return a callable, even if a string view name is given.
        callback = pattern.callback

        # No property setter is provided, so this will have to do.
        pattern._callback = login_required(callback)

        yield pattern
```

Using it works like this (the call to `list` is required because of the `yield`).

```
urlpatterns = list(login_required_patterns('', url(r'^$', home_view)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Would be possible to have a single starting point for all the `urls` in a sort of include and that decorate it using this packages https://github.com/vorujack/decorate_url.

Answer (score 1):

There's an app that provides a plug-and-play solution to this:

https://github.com/mgrouchy/django-stronghold

```sh
pip install django-stronghold
```

```py
# settings.py

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    #...
    'stronghold',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    #...
    'stronghold.middleware.LoginRequiredMiddleware',
)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the answer for Newer versions of Django. It works pretty well!

https://pypi.org/project/django-login-required-middleware/

works with:

- **Python:** 3.6, 3.7, 3.8
- **Django:** 1.11, 2.0, 2.1, 2.2, **3.x**

Answer (score 0):

You can't really win this.  You simply *must* make a declaration of the authorization requirements.   Where else would you put this declaration except right by the view function?

Consider replacing your view functions with callable objects.

```
class LoginViewFunction( object ):
    def __call__( self, request, *args, **kw ):
        p1 = self.login( request, *args, **kw )
        if p1 is not None:
            return p1
        return self.view( request, *args, **kw )
    def login( self, request )
        if not request.user.is_authenticated():
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/login/?next=%s' % request.path)
    def view( self, request, *args, **kw ):
        raise NotImplementedError
```

You then make your view functions subclasses of `LoginViewFunction`.

```
class MyRealView( LoginViewFunction ):
    def view( self, request, *args, **kw ):
        .... the real work ...

my_real_view = MyRealView()
```

It doesn't save any lines of code.  And it doesn't help the "we forgot" problem.  All you can do is examine the code to be sure that the view functions are objects.  Of the right class.

But even then, you'll never really know that *every* view function is correct without a unit test suite.

Comment: I can't win?  But I have to win!  Losing is not an option!

But seriously, I'm not trying to avoid declaring my auth requirements.  I just want to reverse what needs to be declared.  Instead of having to declare all private views and say nothing about public ones, I want to declare all public views and have the default be private.

Comment: Also, neat idea for views-as-classes...  But I think rewriting the hundreds of views in my app at this point is probably a non-starter.

Comment: @samtregar: You have to win?  I have to have a new Bentley.  Seriously.  You can grep for `def`'s.  You can trivially write a very short script to scan all `def`'s in all view modules and determine if a @login_required was forgotten.

Comment: @S.Lott That is the lamest possible way to do this, but yeah, I guess it would work.  Except how do you know which defs are views?  Just looking at functions in views.py won't work, helper shared functions there don't need @login_required.

Comment: Yes, it's lame.  Almost the lamest I could think of.  You don't know which defs are views except by examining the `urls.py`.

Comment: Or by convention. Consistently name your helpers _foo(), i.e. with leading underscore, and filter them out when grep'ing.