# Restrict access to all the pages in a django app

Tags: django

I want to restrict access to all `url(r'^engg/', include('engg.urls')),` and
allow users to access them only if `request.user.profile.type is 'E'` . What is a simple way to do this except creating a decorator and applying it to every single view in engg/views.py ?

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to decorate each view separately you should use use a [middleware](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter17.html).

Shouldn't be to hard to adapt the examples in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2164069/best-way-to-make-djangos-login-required-the-default).