# Limit access on website's parts (Django)

Tags: django

I have the website where I need to limit users access to the website's parts. To keep it simple let's say while website is in beta - I want only registered users can see the website and all the parts. But later I will want to remove those limits.

What I can do - do this login in the template level. Like in all the templates I can have `{% if user.is_authenticated %}` and then just show some message if not.

Second thing which is in my minds - I can define middleware which will check if the user is logged in and if not - redirect him to the login page.

I see bad thing about the template solution, because after I will release the website out of beta, I will need to modify a lot of templates...

What else I can choose here?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to make Django's login_required the default](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2164069/best-way-to-make-djangos-login-required-the-default)

Answer (score 0):

You must tag all methods or classes involved with the [login_required decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#the-login-required-decorator). If you're using generic views, set `login_required=True` when defining them in urls.py.

Comment: and then after I will move out of beta, I need to remove those @login_required... Also I don't like this because I have same modules shared by the separate sites and on one site I don't want to limit access to it for example.

Comment: After you've put note about urls.py changes I'm starting to like it :) Need to investigate. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry Ignas, I misread your question. I feel your middleware solution is probably the best idea. Consider my answer withdrawn.

Comment: Actually, now you mention it, you could just make the login_required bit a configurable variable in settings.py.

Comment: Probably I will go with middleware. Thanks for the comments!