# Best way to make Flask-Login's login_required the default

Tags: python, flask

Like this question: [Best way to make Django's login_required the default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2164069/best-way-to-make-djangos-login-required-the-default)

I'm using `Flask-Login`'s [login_required](http://packages.python.org/Flask-Login/#flaskext.login.login_required) decorator now. Is there anyway to make it the default behavior in `Flask`?

Comment: Maybe you can overwrite some function like full_dispatch_request()  and do the logic there, then call real view if validation passed. More about this function and other API functions (where you can find the function you need) http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Flask.full_dispatch_request Or firstly you can try before_request decorator, but not sure if you will have all the data needed in that state. Haven't done this myself, so sorry can't give more precise answer or code example.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "default behavior" ? Do you mean ALL view functions should have login_required by default ?

Comment: @codegeek yes, except for some white-listed views which I can define in my configuration file.

Comment: @IgnasB. Thank you for your hint. I will check the `full_dispatch_request` function

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I did this in my [instruments](https://github.com/MalphasWats/instruments) project. I use the `before_request` decorator:

```
@app.before_request
def check_valid_login():
    login_valid = 'user' in session # or whatever you use to check valid login

    if (request.endpoint and 
        'static' not in request.endpoint and 
        not login_valid and 
        not getattr(app.view_functions[request.endpoint], 'is_public', False) ) :
        return render_template('login.html', next=request.endpoint)
```

and I then created an `is_public()` decorator for the few places that would need to be accessible without login:

```
def public_endpoint(function):
    function.is_public = True
    return function
```

Comment: I think 'static' not in request.endpoint isn't quite right - maybe something like request.endpoint == 'static', or request.endpoint.startswith('static/')?

Comment: This solution will `raise KeyError` instead of 404 responses. So, it's good to catch them.

Comment: Please check my answer below why relying on solely checking static keyword in the route might be a security concern.

Answer (score 18):

If you are using blueprints and need to protect an entire blueprint with a login, you can make the entire `before_request` to require login.

This is what I use for my CMS blueprint:

```
@cms.before_request
@login_required
def before_request():
    if g.user.role != ROLE_ADMIN:
        abort(401)
```

If you need only to check if the user is logged in (and not if the user has privileges) you can simply `pass` the function

Answer (score 16):

This is a follow up ( *bit more pythonic but thats debatable* ) to @MalphasWats
already great answer.

Also includes an **important security fix** suggested by @nonagon.

Explanation of the vulnerability with `'static' in request.endpoint`:

Imagine that there is route which can be user defiened in some way, like a profile link for example.

If the user sets his name lets say Static Joe, then:

`"Static Joe" --slugifys--> /usr/profiles/static_joe`.

This way making this route public. This is just asking for trouble.

---

Here is the route guard function which is appened before every request handling:

```
@app.before_request
def check_route_access():
    if any([request.endpoint.startswith('static/'),
            current_user.is_authenticated,  # From Flask-Login
            getattr(app.view_functions[request.endpoint],'is_public',False)]):
        return  # Access granted
    else:
        return redirect(url_for('users.login_page'))
```

( *[Flask-Login](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is an excellent module and makes session handling a breeze* )

And here is the decorator ( @public_route ) which you can use to allow access to special pages that need public access by default. (register page, login page):

```
def public_route(decorated_function):
    decorated_function.is_public = True
    return decorated_function
```

Comment: For people who are using `Flask-OIDC` instead of `Flask-Login`, you may also need to add `request.path.startswith('/oidc/callback')` to the condition for granting access

Comment: Good answer but there is a typo in the code - should be current_user.is_authenticated  NOT current_user.is_authenticated()

Comment: Yeah, for sure this was working code. Maybe they updated Flask-Login to use prop instead.

Answer (score 1):

I had to secure a REST API and I have solved finally like this:

```
@app.before_request
@auth.login_required
def login_required_for_all_request():    
    pass
```

(Actually I used also the connexion framework so I had to use: @app.app.before_request  )

Comment: Just brilliant :-)