# Adding auth decorators to flask restx

Tags: python, flask, flask-restplus, flask-restx

I have a Flask application using `flask-restx` and `flask-login`.  I would like all routes by default to require login, and explicitly define public routes that require no authentication.  I have started using decorators following the example given in this question:

[Best way to make Flask-Login's login_required the default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13428708/best-way-to-make-flask-logins-login-required-the-default)

It works for function endpoints, but not for `restx` resource endpoints.

I have tried adding the function both as a decorator, and using the `method_decorators` field. For example:

```
def public_route(decorated_function):
    """
    This is a decorator to specify public endpoints in our flask routes
    :param decorated_function:
    :return:
    """
    decorated_function.is_public = True
    return decorated_function


class HelloWorld(ConfigurableResource):

    method_decorators = {"get": [public_route]}

    @public_route
    @api.doc('Welcome message')
    def get(self):
        return {'hello': 'world'}
```

And this test passes:

```
def test_hello_world_is_public():
    api = Namespace('health', description='Health related operations')
    hello = HelloWorld(api, config=None, logger=None)
    is_public_endpoint = getattr(hello.get, 'is_public', False)
    assert is_public_endpoint
```

My challenge is I can't see how to access this attribute in my auth logic:

```
    @app.before_request
    def check_route_access():
        """
        This function decides whethere access should be granted to an endpoint.
        This function runs before all requests.
        :return:
        """
        is_public_endpoint = getattr(app.view_functions[request.endpoint], 'is_public', False)

        if person_authorized_for_path(current_user, request.path, is_public_endpoint):
            return
        # Otherwise access not granted
        return redirect(url_for("auth.index"))
```

This works for plain function endpoints, but not restx resources.

I understand that `restx` is wrapping my resource class in a function so that flask can do dispatch, but I can't figure out how to access the decorator from here.  So I have some questions:

- Is it possible to reach the decorator from the view_function?
- Is it possible to know whether the endpoint is a restx resource or a plain rest function?
- Is there a better way to do what I'm trying to achieve?

Answer (score 4):

Based on [this](https://github.com/python-restx/flask-restx/blob/0.2.0/flask_restx/resource.py#L27) and [this](https://github.com/python-restx/flask-restx/blob/0.2.0/flask_restx/resource.py#L39-L40), `method_decorators` variable should be a list of functions, so you should use it like:

```
def _perform_auth(method):
    is_public_endpoint = getattr(method, 'is_public', False)
    # place the validation here

class Resource(flask_restx.Resource):
    method_decorators = [_perform_auth]
```

Comment: Is there a way to apply that method_decorator globally so I don't have to put it on every Resource? I tried adding the perform_auth function to the `decorators` arguments of Api and Namespace but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: sure. you just need to inherit all your resource classes from the 'Resource' class described in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to reach the decorator from the view_function?

Well... it is *possible*, but I wouldn't recommend it. Here's an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39078467/python-how-to-get-the-calling-function-not-just-its-name)

> Is it possible to know whether the endpoint is a restx resource or a
> plain rest function?

You probably can inspect the func and figure out if it's from restx, maybe looking at `__qualname__`, but then again, I`d wouldn't recommend it.

> Is there a better way to do what I'm trying to achieve?

I would go one of these solutions:

- Explicitly decorate view_funcs and resources that do need authentication, instead of the other way around
- Create a blueprint for public endpoints, a blueprint for protected endpoints with the `before_request` decorator for authorization

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar use case.I wanted to apply a decorator to specific endpoints ( here all routes except get methods) by using flask-restx default decorator.

This is my solution.

```
def check_role_except_get(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args,**kwargs):
        if func.__name__ == "get"
            return func(*args,**kwargs)
        else:
              ........ Authorization Logic Here / Abort if Authorization fails----
    return wrapper


def authorization(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args,**kwargs):
        func.view_class.method_decorators = [check_role_except_get]
        return func(*args,**kwargs)
    return wrapper

api = Api(app, version='1.0', title='My API',
    description='A simple API',decorators=[authorization]
)
ns = api.namespace('todos', description='TODO operations')

@ns.route('/')
class TodoList(Resource):
    '''Shows a list of all todos, and lets you POST to add new tasks'''
    def get(self):
        '''List all tasks'''
        return "resp"

    def post(self):
        '''Create a new task'''
        return resp
```