# login_required decorator for urls of whole app

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

I have a `url(r'^manager/', include('manager.urls'))` and I want only logged in users can access it.  So, I tried to write `url(r'^manager/', login_required(include('manager.urls'))),` but it throws

```
TypeError at /manager/

'tuple' object is not callable
```

Is there other way to implement it or should I write `@login_required` decorator for every view in `manager.views.py`?

Answer (score 0):

`login_required` is a decorator, meaning that it requires a function, in contrast to the `include()` function which returns a tuple of urls.

As a simple solution I would recommend you to apply the decorator on each individual url within the file `managers.url`.

Otherwise take a look at [Best way to make Django's login_required the default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2164069/best-way-to-make-djangos-login-required-the-default).

Comment: regret... how about DRY? :(

Comment: Ok, I edited it for you to get some not-so-elegant alternatives. But do you really want to get involved into that I wonder. Personally, I don't find a `login_required` call to each url much of a repeatition to bother myself.