# Using Django Login Required Mixin

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I have a class based view which I would like to make accessible only when a user is logged in, and I would like to redirect unauthenticated users back to the index page

This is the view in question:

```
class ArtWorkCreate(CreateView, LoginRequiredMixin):
    login_url = '/login/'
    redirect_field_name = 'login'
    model = ArtWork
    fields = ['userID','title','medium','status','price','description']
```

This is the related Model

```
class ArtWork(models.Model):
    userID= models.ForeignKey(MyUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    medium = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    price = models.FloatField()
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=4, default="SALE")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

And this is the related URL

```
 url(r'artwork/add/$', ArtWorkCreate.as_view(), name='artwork-add'),
```

and this is the URL I would like to redirect to where the user is NOT logged id

```
  url(r'^index/$', views.index, name='index'),
```

My goal is to make the form only accessbile to logged in user where they can only add an artwork item under their own name

and lastly this is the model form

```
class ArtWorkForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ArtWork
        fields = ['title','medium','status','price','description']
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to make Django's login\_required the default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2164069/best-way-to-make-djangos-login-required-the-default)

Comment: Not the solution, but you should put the mixins before the CreateView (or other class based view)

Comment: (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin)[https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin]

Answer (score 26):

We should inherit the `LoginRequiredMixin` first. because python will consider the method `dispatch` from the first inherited class(in this case).

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class ArtWorkCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    login_url = '/index/'
    redirect_field_name = 'index'
    model = ArtWork
```

Comment: this always gets me

Answer (score 5):

Just Define a Login url on the settings.py file
(also remove the login url on the class)

```
#settings.py

LOGIN_URL = 'login'
```

Answer (score 0):

login_url is  URL that users who don’t pass the test/authentication will be redirected to.

redirect_field_name attribute should be set to URL the user should be redirected to after a successful login.

Source:https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.AccessMixin.get_login_url