# how can i make login required for an entire urlconf in django

Tags: python, django

I have the following code in root url conf

```
path('dashboard/', include('frontend.urls')),
```

so inorder to make a url login protected I have to go to the `frontend->urls.py` and add the following code (the **login_required** decorator) for each of the paths

```
 path('lists', login_required(EmailListView.as_view(),login_url='/login'), name="list"),
```

which is quiet tedious, and we might forget as well. So my question is how can I enable login_required protection for a urlconf group? is there any way I can enable it from the root urlconf? like below?

```
path('dashboard/', login_required(include('frontend.urls'))), 
#something like this?
#for now I am not able to access any urls if I do this
```

so that the entire set is protected !!,

**NB:** I read this answer here [Best way to make Django's login_required the default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2164069/best-way-to-make-djangos-login-required-the-default),

still, this requires specification of urls in some other place,

`Django 2.1`, `Python 3.6`

Comment: Have you found anyway to do this ?..

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/67529174/2520933

Answer (score 0):

Django 4.2.4 still can't find anyway to do it.
Workaround for me is :

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class MyListView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    ....
```